# change format from sql output

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, discord.py

I am coding an discord bot rn and i want to output all values out of an column in an specific format.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator=True)
async def listchannel(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        return

    guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)

    channel = await bot.pg_con.fetch("SELECT channel_id FROM anticrash WHERE guild_id = $1", guild_id)

    if not channel:
        await ctx.send(f'No channel was not added to this server: {guild_id}')
        return
    
    await ctx.send(f"{channel}")
```

and the output is like this

```
[<Record channel_id='847854890985980005'>, <Record channel_id='847546806937059341'>]
```

but i want to change the output to this format

```
<#847854890985980005>, <#847546806937059341>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over your record list and get the attribute you want, then add it to a string

```py
message = ""

for record in channel:
    message += f"<#{record['channel_id']}> ,"

await ctx.send(message)
```

If you want a one-liner:

```py
message = ', '.join([f"<#{record['channel_id']}>" for record in channel])
await ctx.send(message)
```

Comment: So i put the code in and i got an module error

"TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable"

Comment: **full** traceback please

Comment: Ah yes sorry, how have you defined this `[<Record channel_id='847854890985980005'>, <Record channel_id='847546806937059341'>]`? Is it `channel`?

Comment: yes, channel was the def. that i used to select it from the sql